# SQL error #1064. Alter table with default values

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, ddl, alter-table

I tried to do an `ALTER TABLE` to add some columns with a default value. Why I do I have this error?

I tried with:

```
column_name varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

and also with

```
column_name varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
```

but it didn't work in both.

```
ALTER TABLE utenti
ADD
missileBalistico varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
missileBalisticoPotenza varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 60,
...,
aiuti varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

It gaves me 31 same errors:

```
Unrecognized alter operation. (near "," at position ...)
```

And MySQL said:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 60,
basi varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
vitaBa' at line 4
```

Comment: Why are you apparently storing numbers in varchar columns? Use a suitable numeric type instead

Comment: @ADyson no because it can be a word too

Comment: I see. Your default values gave me and others the impression the fields were all intended to store numbers. It was a bit unclear that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use several `add` clauses:

```
ALTER TABLE utenti
ADD missileBalistico varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
ADD missileBalisticoPotenza varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 60,
-- Other add clauses...
ADD aiuti varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

Comment: Just do not specify numbers as default values for strings. Why the OP would store numbers as strings is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are using ’N’ instead of 'N' as DEFAULT value while coding. I would recommend you to check it on your editor.